# All connections dropping down after a while

Tags: connection-issues, huawei

Lately I started to have this degrading connectivity problem.

1. (one month ago) When connecting my laptop in tethering, through WiFi from the Android hotspot, the internet connection (on the smartphone side) was dropping completely; I needed to set the *Airplane Mode* fist **Off**, then **On**.
2. (last two weeks) I noticed that the internet connectivity was dropping (the usual *H/3g/E/G* symbols were not there) after some time from the restoring (still turning **Off/On** the *Airplane Mode*, or restarting the phone).
3. (last week) Together with the loosing of connectivity it started to **not call** or **receive** calls. Moreover the **same exact thing happens** at the same time **for the WiFi connectivity**.
   Sometimes I could restore the functionality. Other times it didn't work for a lot of time, even restarting everything.
   **Note: the carrier icon shows a full/strong signal (but just doesn't work for real)**

A couple of other infos:

- in the last months the display has started to flicker; so I suspect there should be some battery problem (like not enough tension). But except for that everything always worked perfectly
- I almost finished the space on the phone, so it is slowed down. But anyway everything for working fairly.

What could be the reason?
Is most probable an hardware problem? Should I change phone?
Or is something I could fix on the software?

*My phone:*

- Huawei Y300
- Android 4.1.1
- Rooted
- With Dr.Web antivirus

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of troubles before(not screen flicker).

You could try to factory reset and make fresh clean install of stock firmware. 
Edit: **Remember to backup your data**.

If you are using some custom rom flash it after doing stock and make sure to check from [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=Huawei%20Y300) if anyone is experiencing similar issues.

Issue could be related to some sort of corruption which could happen if flashing went wrong or tweaking while rooted.

Normally when flashing orginal stock firmware this fixes issue.

You could also try to check SIM card(take off put back) and take battery off for few minutes(this preforms soft reset and sometimes could fix some problems).

This brand is not familiar to me but i hope this helps to your problem.